# Hard code product images in Magento with dynamic references

Tags: image, magento, dynamic, reference, src

In Magento, I have a page where I'm hard coding the images of certain products. Rather than simply using the products' image URLs to do so, I'd like to use dynamic references to the products' associated images so that if I change the product's image, the reference on this page won't break. I need both thumbnail size images and large images. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the product object already as `$_product`

```
$thumbImageUrl =  Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($width, $height);
$imageUrl =  Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize($width, $height);
// if you don't want to resize at all
$imageUrl = $_product->getMediaConfig()->getMediaUrl($_product->getData('image'));
```